# How to add cart rule for specific categories in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have magento 2.2.3 store, I am try to add shopping cart rule for products in specific categories only.But if someone adds has one product from selected categories and has more products from unselected categories the discount applies to all products.I was wondering if I am doing something wrong. please see attached image.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget below setting. Hope this help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstand about Cart Price Rule. If you configured the condition for a specific category, so this rule will be applied for the items that validated but not all.

Example:

- My cart rule sets 10% discount for category =4
- On my cart, I add 2 products:

  1. The first one has category 3 and the price is $7
  2. The second one has category 4 and the price is $64

=> So the cart price rule only applied for the second one and the discount amount will be -$6.4 (not $7.1)

See the attached image for the detail:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have need to add category condition in Action.

For fix the cart price apply in selected category you can also add below condition. Also add category as you needed.

**Click on Actions tab and set category condition as you want:**

**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).**

> If **ALL** of these conditions are **TRUE**:
>
> Category **is 186,192,193,194,190,187,etc...**

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

How to set free shipping on only one specific category on magento2